# What is this array doing in every case?

Tags: c

I'm reading the K&R book, and I got stuck at arrays (inside the introduction). I don't want to put more questions inside this one but the "general question" here is that I did not understand how to use arrays and I feel like the book explained them very poorly at the introduction.
This program counts numbers (separatedly), blank spaces, and others.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    }

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        }

        else if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        {
            ++nwhite;
        }

        else
        {
            ++nother;
        }
    }

    printf("digits =");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    }
    printf(", blanks = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);

    return 0;
}
```

I did understand that the first 'for' is making every value of `ndigit[i]` to 0. After that I lost it. It says "If `i` equals between 0 or 9, what does `ndigit[c-'0']` mean?" Really, what is that '0'. And the last part is that it makes another 'for' with `i`,  what happened to the value of `i` if `i` is inside ndigit?
I shouldn't be asking this; it's too novice but I don't know where else to get help.

Comment: A good way to understand how code works is to run it in your debugger, single-stepping through the code and watching how the variables change.

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm interested because of your comment, I'm using Code::Blocks, and I don't really understand how to run it on debug.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Code::Blocks but pretty much any respectable IDE should let you do basic source level debugging. Does it come with a manual ?

Comment: Ugh, I'm answering too late, I don't really know if it comes with a manual, you see I started pretty raw on programming, first it was interest, then I just started coding the stuff I learned, if you do know of an excelent IDE just tell me, I do like Code::Blocks but I've seen people that use Dev-C++ and a few others, I'm just familiar with Code::Blocks, so your recommendation will be useful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Windows person, so I wouldn't know what to recommend for beginners. I understand that there is a free version of Visual Studio that you can get from Microsoft though - I believe it's the Express edition.

Comment: Also, I forgot, @Paul R, I've tried using Visual Studio Express 2013, but to compile a C program I need to use the Windows console. I should look more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to start off the while loop runs until you enter a `End of File` (on Windows `Ctrl + Z`; on Unix systems `Ctrl + D`)

Until that happens, it reads in 1 character every time. Then it goes through the `if` statements to check if it is a number (`0-9`) or a new line (`\n`), space (`[space here]`), tab (`\t`) or something else.

And it increments (+1) the specific variable or at a specific array index for the numbers. (This: `c-'0'` is to convert the character to a int, so you can access the array and increment the specific value, which presupposes that you have initialize your array with 0's.)

At the end it prints how many characters/numbers you have entered.

Answer (score 1):

The character codes for the digits `'0'` .. `'9'` are consecutive numbers, usually 48 .. 57.  If `c` is in the range `'0'` to `'9'` (which the `if` test has checked), then `ndigit[c-'0']++` increments the count for subscript `0` if the character is `'0'`, and for subscript `9` if the character is `'9'`, and similarly for values in between.  (Note that you can use any integer valued expression as a subscript — but the value needs to be in the range of valid subscripts for the array or the behaviour is undefined — a specialized term in C which means 'anything can happen, including it might work as you expected, or crashing the program, or the computer, or … anything'.)

C mandates that the 10 digits have consecutive code values, with `'0'` coded lower than `'1'`.  Note that telephony used to treat 0 as being 10 (it was hard to spot 0 clicks, but not hard to spot 10 clicks in the days of rotary phones).

Comment: Thank you, I did know that every character has an ASCII value but didn't know that '0' was to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

`c-'0'` converts the character to its integer number:

- '0' becomes the integer 0
- '1' becomes 1
- ...

So, `ndigit[c-'0']` refers to the counter of the current character.

Answer (score 0):

In C every character is assigned a value. You can look them up [here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html).
**'0'** has a value of **48** and **'9'** has a value of **57**.

Since `c-'0'` in `ndigit[c-'0']` needs to be a value between **0** and **9** you simply subtract the **'0'**.

Comment: Other encodings than ASCII may be used (although in all of them, `'0'` through `'9'` are consecutive, so this trick always works)

Answer (score 0):

when `c == '0'`, `c-'0'` is equal to `0`.
when `c == '9'`, `c-'0'` is equal to `9`.

You can interpolate the values when `c` is between `'0' - '9'`.

When `c-'0'` is equal to `0`,

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

increments the value of `ndigit[0]`.

When `c-'0'` is equal to `9`,

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

increments the value of `ndigit[9]`.

You can interpolate what happens when `c` is between `'0' - '9'`.

Answer (score 0):

With `c-'0'` you're getting real number value from ASCII value.

Take a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Character `'1'` which you can load with `getchar()`, has ascii value **49**. If you substract value of character `'0'` from it, you get real value **1**.

Answer (score 0):

In computer's memory, all characters are represented by integer numbers, i.e. their *codes*.

In a C program, `'0'` (a `char` literal) is essentially an *integer* value (code) for character 0, according to the encoding being used.
In modern systems, the code of character 0 is 48, the code for character 1 is 49, etc. (see [ASCII encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).) So, `'0' == 48`, `'1' == 49` etc.

In this program, a *character* digit (i.e. a *code* of a digit) is converted to the *numerical value* of the digit, so that `ndigits[0]` would count zeroes, `ndigits[1]` would count 1's, etc. `c - '0'` performs this conversion, using the fact that the encoding for digits is dense, and the digits in the encoding table are ordered.

```
 c  |  c - '0'
----+--------------------------
'0' |  '0' - '0' = 48 - 48 = 0
'1' |  '1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1 (Code of '1' is 49.)
'2' |  '2' - '0' = 50 - 48 = 2 (Code of '2' is 50.)
   ...
'9' |  '9' - '0' = 57 - 48 = 9
```

`ndigits[i]` means `i`-th item of array `ndigits`. E.g. when `i` is 0, `ndigits[i]` = `ndigits[0]` = the first (indices start at 0) item of the array.